# Select users with common answers to questions

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have four models and a CustomUser table.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=140)
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=70)
class Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='responses')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Each question has multiple answers but each user can only pick one answer to each question.

Each user can answer multiple questions.

How do I select a list of users with a nested list of their common answers to a reference user with just the ORM?

I can think of a hacky solution of retrieving the list of common answers and then a python loop to increment the count for each user but I would like to confine it to the ORM as I need to append this to a parent serializer (UserSerializer -> ResponseSerializer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `Prefetch` object here, like:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

user_answers = Answer.objects.filter(response__user=reference_user)

CustomUser.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'response_set',
        queryset=Response.objects.filter(answer__in=user_answers),
        to_attr='common_answers'
    )
)
```

Now the `CustomUser`s that arise from this queryset, will have an extra attribute `common_answers` with `Response` objects that will contain `Response`s with an `Answer` that they share with *`reference_user`*.

If you are only looking for users that have at least one common answer with *`reference_user`*, you can filter out the others with:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(
    response__answer__response__user=reference_user
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'response_set',
        queryset=Response.objects.filter(answer__in=user_answers),
        to_attr='common_answers'
    )
).distinct()
```

Comment: don't you also need a clause to filter out any users with empty common_answers? like `.exclude(common_answers=None)` or is that somehow handled by this?

Comment: @bryan60: well after rereading the question, I have the impression that all `CustomUser`s are returned, and in case there are no comoon answers it will yield an empty list?

Comment: possibly, my reading is that OP wants only users with common answers, but it is vague

Comment: To clear this up, yes, I would like to filter out the users with empty common_answers. Do I pass this prefetched query through a serializer as though common_answers is a field of CustomUser (common_answers = ResponseSerializer)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm getting 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'common_answers' in the serializer.

Comment: @Joshua: I can not reproduce that error. Are you sure that you passed the correct queryset to the serializer?

Comment: I tried to prefetch to a model that has user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser) by replacing 'response_set' with 'user__response_set'. I added related_name='response' to the user field on the Response model and now it's throwing a different error - Cannot find 'response_set' on CustomUser object, 'user__response_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: @Joshua: did you use a `related_name` from the reference from `Response` to `CustomUser`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the Response model to `user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='response')`

Comment: @Joshua: then you should use `__response` instead of `response_set`. Note that a ForeignKey is a many-to-one relation, so that `related_names` are usually *plural* however.

Comment: I've switched the related_name to 'responses' and the prefetch reference to 'user__responses' and I'm back to the original error `object has no attribute 'common_answers'`. `AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `common_answers` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`.`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've edited the original question with all the changes I've made and the error I've received.

Comment: @Joshua: are you sure you are not passing other querysets to the serializer as well *without* this prefetch. Perhaps it errors on other views? It might be better to make a specific serializer for this one since only the one with this queryset will evidenlty have a `common_answers` attribute.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, this serializer is used exclusively for this queryset and there is only one view being accessed right now. There is something missing with the prefetch query as printing the queryset shows that there is no `common_answers` attribute.

Comment: @Joshua: I've tested this locally, and the queryset, has for `list(qs)[0].common_answers` a list `[<Response: Response object (2)>]` locally ...

Comment: @Joshua: are you sure the `get_queryset` runs (perhaps you can add a print statement)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have a print statement right after the prefetch line and it only prints out the Profile record with no common_answers. I tried printing ret.values()[0].common_answers and I got `'dict' object has no attribute 'common_answers'`. Just to confirm we're on the same page, I'm using the first block of code you posted without the filter.

Comment: @Joshua: but you here use `.values()`? By using `.values()` the prefetching will get lost (since `Prefetch` is a "promise" to later perform extra fetches and do the join "in memory").

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've tried `list(ret)[0].common_answers` and got `'Profile' object has no attribute 'common_answers'`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem After some time away from the screen, I feel like this has gone off-tangent from the original question and I'm sorry for turning a quick answer into such a lengthy problem. I'm marking your solution as the solution to the original question and opening a more specific query regarding the new issue. Thank you!